# What are these window springs called?

Tags: windows

Our double hung windows have 2 of the pictured springs on each light. We
have several broken ones. The lower end is nailed into the glass window
frame. The other end is is one piece, all plastic and has a protrusion (slightly bent molded plastic pin) that fits into a small hole at the top of the window frame. It's an extension spring not a torsion spring.

When the windows are closed, the springs are covered by a round plastic tube and the springs are extended, bare but hidden, by the window itself. As the window is opened the spring retracts into the tube and the tube gets covered by the window itself.

Any idea what these are called?

I keep finding similar ones but with torsion springs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VlbQHptDBGmNnPRxz6lPUh_8HLmehWKu/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VfRU2HaZO924y0r1nBw-2ndp8d7bv0y1/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I know what you asked for, but it wouldn't let me add them. It kept saying they were to large even at 78kb. For some reason the same pics worked this time

Comment: I removed the "where do I find them" portion because that's a shopping question and off-topic. Once you know what to call them, I'm sure you'll be able to find them. In the mean time, have you called any local window repair places to ask them what they're called? Probably won't find the info at a big-box store, but someone who specialized in windows would probably be able to help you out.

Comment: We had some like that in a farmhouse my parents bought back around 1970.  Saw a few variants in the 70s, but none before or since.

Comment: It's built in 71 so that timeframe makes sense